# How to change sshd listening port on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ssh, services

I want to change the default port for sshd daemon in Mac OS X 10.6

Changing the sshd_config file seems to be useless, I suppose becouse of sshd is started by launchd.

I'm looking for **the real solution**, not a workaround as google is full :)

Any suggestion?

Comment: There's a similar question on serverfault: [How to change sshd port on Mac OS X?](http://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x). Maybe you'll find more information there.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, after looking to launchd.plist man.

As pointed out by @alex, there is the same question on SF. [I answered there](https://serverfault.com/questions/18761/how-to-change-sshd-port-on-mac-os-x/67616#67616).

Sorry for not having seen it on SF, but it seems to me that it is a SU related question. :)

Comment: I think it's more serverfault. Actually, to me, anything that deals with ports and ssh is serverfault :)

Comment: eheh, ok de gustibus :)